# Understanding Windows application footprint

Tags: windows, computer-forensics

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for documentations that specifies what a Window application's file footprint is?

More specifically, I am looking for a documentation that specifies what registry files (and which hive) and files/directories must be created when an application is installed.

Comment: There are no requirements. Some programs do not create any registry entries and in extreme cases (so-called "portable apps") do not even create any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raymond Chen is totally right, however, there are some pretty common places to put things in the registry\file system based on the programs needs.  I.E. Does it start on login or start up?  It really depends on how the program interfaces with Windows.  Hopefully that points you in the right direction.